# Angular-seed protractor throws error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, protractor

I try run angular-seed on my computer (Windows 10, last update) https://github.com/angular/angular-seed. Web works fine, but I have problem with protractor. Karma runs, but when I try protractor > npm run protractor I get these error.

```
E:\angular-seed>npm run protractor

> angular-seed@0.0.0 preprotractor E:\angular-seed
> npm run update-webdriver


> angular-seed@0.0.0 preupdate-webdriver E:\angular-seed
> npm install

npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported

> angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall E:\angular-seed
> bower install


> angular-seed@0.0.0 update-webdriver E:\angular-seed
> webdriver-manager update

selenium standalone is up to date.
chromedriver is up to date.

> angular-seed@0.0.0 protractor E:\angular-seed
> protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js

Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
events.js:141
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

Error: spawn java ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:855:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:455:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:17)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "protractor"
npm ERR! node v5.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-seed@0.0.0 protractor: `protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 protractor script 'protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-seed package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-seed
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\angular-seed\npm-debug.log
```

I have all up to date. I clone from git today and run npm update. It is my problem or it is package problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Home page of Angular seed doesn't mentioned that, but protractor has dependency on JDK. Do you have it installed? You can check this by

```
java --version
```